# Laravel: How to add a drop down list to user registration form

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to add a drop down list to the Laravel user registration form. I have been successful with showing the drop down list in the front end and registering new user. However when I check the DB, there's no record in the column.

What I want to do is have new user register their location and, id corresponding to the location be added in the DB.

**register.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Shop Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="location" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Location') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="location" type="text" class="form-control @error('location') is-invalid @enderror" name="location" value="{{ old('location') }}" required autocomplete="location">                                        
                                    @foreach(config('pref') as $key => $score)                                        
                                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $score }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('location')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'location' => ['required', 'string', 'not_in: 0'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'location' => $data['location'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**pref.php**

```
    <?php 
return array(
  '0' => 'not selected',
  '1' => 'New York', 
  '2' => 'Los Angeles', 
  '3' => 'Texas', 
);
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'location',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function tests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Test');
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

[dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4r68.png)

Comment: Have you added `location` in the fillables array in the User model?

Comment: Yes, I have added location in the fillables array.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? If not I'd like to help you debug.

Comment: Hi,
Actually I'm still struggling...
I think the problem is in the register.blade.php but I haven't figured out where. If you have any advice, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Ok, let's start with ensuring that the create method received the data, although I feel like it did. Can you do a `dd($data)` before the return in the create method in your controller and see if it has the location data?

Comment: Hey there,
I did the dd($data) and here are the results.

`array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "L3FRXBKUzDJmUBUsKwl36dI0CcMTEciXumcEX9lq"
  "name" => "aaa"
  "location" => "3"
  "email" => "abcde@gmail.com"
  "password" => "abcde"
  "password_confirmation" => "abcde"
]`

It seems like the method is receiving the data.

Comment: Can you dd the entire return. Instead of return you do: `dd(User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'location' => $data['location'],
        ]);)`

Comment: Or just do `dd(User::create($data));` (just for testing, password wont be hashed here)

Comment: The result was too long so I added at the bottom of my question as an image. Please click on the dd link. Now it seems like maybe location is no received...

Comment: The expanded fillables array doesnt have `location`.  And you shared the User model in `App` namespace and in the controller, it is `App\Model` namespace.

Comment: Please check if the User model in `App\Model` namespace has `location` in the `fillables` array.

Comment: I checked the App\Model and just like you said, I had not added location in the fillables array. I added location and now the id is recorded in the DB! Thank you so much!
Does this mean at some point I unintentionally made two User.php file?

Comment: Looks like that. Best get rid of the redundant file to avoid confusion later on. I'll post this as the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot share, it looks like the request is hitting the User model in the namespace `App\Models` and `locations` is not added in the `fillables` array.

The User model shared in the question has the namespace `App`.

I would advise to get rid of one of the User models to avoid confusions down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in your User model `'location'` is in your `$fillable` array, so that Laravel knows it can be assigned during user registration.

Additionally, I would correct your `not_in: 0` rule to [the format the Validation docs present](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-not-in): `Rule::notIn([0])`

Comment: Hi!
Yes, 'location' is in the $fillable array. I added tho code so you can see.
I also changed the validation to Rule::notIn([0]), but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="location" type="text" class="form-control @error('location') is-invalid @enderror" name="location" value="{{ old('location') }}" required autocomplete="location">
```

Explain what you wanted to get by setting one more "value" field in select?

Comment: Hey there,
So, you mean I need one more "value" field other than value="{{ old('location') }}"?

Comment: This field (value) in the selectbox is written in the options fields. I admit that the empty result gets into the database for this reason.

Comment: <select class='class-name' v-model='result'>
   <option value='0' >Select 0</option>
   <option value='1' >Select 1</option>
</select>